# Saving Browser Session Between Tabs

Tags: session, cookies, browser, local-storage, session-storage

https://www.tiqets.com/

I am wondering how this site keeps track of currency. When I change currency from USD to EUR for example, close the tab, open a new tab, open up the site, it will show EUR currency. But when I inspect local storage, session storage, or cookies, they don't seem to contain any indication of this currency code.

Does anyone know the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Its not becasue of cookies but because of cached. I know cookies also plays vital role on this. 
YOu can check again by deleting all the cached, history, (use cc cleaner) and open the site Vola , its default

Comment: hmm but i tried using incognito and it is still the same

Comment: Then it means, ur ip already logged into their server and recorded your activity. So for that IP it will show the same data, until you have new IP.

Comment: but that is not true as well, i just tested closing the whole browser window, revisit site, and it does not remember the currency

Comment: So, it persists when tab is closed, but it doesn't when window is closed. It sounds like session storage, but upon inspection session storage is clear....